# SAP HANA: Clear or reduce STATISTICS_ALERT_BASE table

Tags: sap-hana

Our SAP HANA database consumes a lot of memory - even though we do not have much data in it.

After some research:

```
select top 100 * from M_CS_TABLES order by MEMORY_SIZE_IN_TOTAL desc
```

I figured out that the STATISTICS_ALERTS_BASE table has a size of over 20.000.000.000 (twenty billion)

How to reduce or clear this table?

**EDIT:**

If the table gets huge it can make the **admin panel** in **SAP HANA** really **slow**. If so then truncate the table fixes the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy :-)

```
truncate table _SYS_STATISTICS.STATISTICS_ALERTS_BASE;
```

have a look at [SAP note 2170779](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2170779). I usually have a cron job getting rid of older alerts with the  "delete older entries" statement described in the note.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Probably I tried with the wrong user (permission denied)

Comment: Thx esp. for the SAP note :)

Comment: bitte sehr... auch wenn "everything HANA" ganz schrecklich verteilt ist lohnt sich das gute alte OSS immer noch.